# Locking the screen via CLI?

Tags: xfce, screen-lock, lightdm

Is there any way that I can lock the screen CLI-style? I'm trying to target as many desktop managers as possible (mostly LightDM, but GDM, KDM, SLiM, XScreensaver, etc. would be great too), but I can only dig things up for GDM and XScreensaver.

For GDM, it would be:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

For XScreensaver:

```
xscreensaver-command -lock
```

Is there a similar command for KDM and LightDM?

Comment: Can you start the screen saver and ssh in and ps and see what screen saver is running and deduce from there what command to run?  (how I found the gnome-screensaver-command)

Comment: `man lightdm` doesn't look too promising... http://www.moleberry.com/man/l/lightdm.1.html

Comment: Perhaps you can try to control them via **d-bus** (using `dbus-send` to send the appropriate lock message).

Comment: @andcoz: I saw a few `dbus-send` things while Googling, but sadly none of them worked. I even looked at the LightDM API reference for a solution, but even that doesn't have anything. Heck, I even tried to look at the source of Ubuntu's user switching panel (sorry, can't read like 1,000,000 of C). I might try emailing the dev list for help...

Comment: @polynomial: That seems like a good solution (maybe post it as an answer?). I don't have a second computer to SSH with, but I can try and print the process list every second or so to deduce what is happening.

Comment: Are you trying to lock the screen while a user is logged in, or while no user is logged in? Gdm and kdm are display managers, i.e. programs that prompt for a user name and password. Did you mean the Gnome and KDE desktop environments?

Comment: See my update to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I Googled/emailed around a bit and got these two commands.

To lock the screen:

```
xflock4
```

To activate user switching:

```
gdmflexiserver
```

For Lightdm, this file resides in a strange spot (at least on Arch Linux):

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm/gdmflexiserver
```

I merged these two into XFCE's logout button dialog, in case anyone's interested, so the patch is available here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=52816

Comment: Xflock4 must have gnome-screensaver

Answer (score 6):

You can lock all screen savers on X by using `xdg-screensaver`

```
xdg-screensaver lock
```

It'll take care of the gory details.

Answer (score 1):

There are several DM-independent, simple solutions like [alock](http://code.google.com/p/alock/), [slock](http://tools.suckless.org/slock) or [xtrlock](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/x/xtrlock/) ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xtrlock.1x.html)). Note that they might not even display any input window prompting for password - you just enter the password while the screen is blank and press Enter (that's the case of `slock` at least).

If you want the locker to be able to display a screensaver and show a custom prompt on un-locking, try `xlock` provided with **xlockmore** package (see [this info](http://www.tux.org/~bagleyd/xlxs.html) and [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xlock.1.html)).

Comment: I'm not looking for a lock screen (I have my own, `plock`, for that :P). I'm looking for a way to *trigger* the lockscreen (whatever it is).

Comment: Then `xautolock` (which is a part of **xlockmore**) provides this functionality - have a look at the last two links I posted and [the `xautolock` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/xautolock.1.html).

Answer (score 1):

For a environment agnostic lock app, there is `i3lock` which also lets you set the lockscreen background.

For LightDM you can run `light-locker` as a background process in your session. It will lock your session as soon as the screensaver starts/system resumes from suspend.

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but working solution for unlock kde or lightdm session from screensaver via cli (command line):

```
qdbus | grep kscreenlocker_greet | xargs -I {} qdbus {} /MainApplication quit
```

Answer (score 0):

If the system use `systemd`, you can use `loginctl`:

```
$ loginctl lock-session
```

See more on [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/loginctl.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LXQt#Installation

```ini
[Screensaver]
lock_command=i3lock
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).